# Ada: Integer Overflow

Tags: overflow, long-integer, ada

so I am hashing and have defined these types/functions:

```
subtype string2 is String(1..2);  
function cString2 is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(string2, long_integer);
function cChar is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(character, long_integer);
```

and MUST use this hash function:

```
HA = (((cString2(s1) + cString2(s2)) * 256) + cChar(char)) mod 128
```

(the function is bad on purpose, but I must implement it) The problem occurs when adding and/or trying to multiply 256 by the sum of the two long integers, for it overflows. I need to somehow treat the strings as POSITIVE integer values and also not have my function overflow. THANKS!!!

Comment: Usually one makes the hash table size a prime number to assure a more even distribution.

Comment: Homework I assume, since you're stuck with a sub-optimal hash function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Long_Integer` is a signed integer type, and guaranteed to cover the range `–2**31+1 .. +2**31–1` (if it exists):

LRM 3.5.4(22):

> If Long_Integer is predefined for an implementation, then its range shall include the range `–2**31+1 .. +2**31–1`.

With your declarations you are likely to include at least 2 bytes of random junk in your converted values, but as the sizes don't match, the result is implementation defined and possibly invalid or abnormal.

I suggest that you read up on the `'Pos` attribute and `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion` in the [LRM](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TOC.html).

Comment: I solved my problem, I created a modular type that allowed me to hold even bigger numbers

Comment: it is, im getting my desired hash values, my modular type is allowing me to have 2^64 positive integers, so no more overflow

Comment: Have you tried to compare the hash values you get on big and little endian machines?  Have you tried to compare the hash values with what you get from calculating by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the quality of various `Hash` functions using the approach shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jumbleada#sec2), which tallies collisions in a hash table of dictionary words. The resulting `Counts` are stored in an instance of [`Ada.Containers.Ordered_Maps`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-6.html).

As a concrete example, the library `Hash` function

```
function Hash is new Ada.Strings.Bounded.Hash(ASB);
```

produces a result having unique hashes for over half of the words and just seven collisions in the worst case:

```
Word count: 235886
Table size: 393241
Load factor: 59.99%
 0: 215725 (0.00%)
 1: 129710 (54.99%)
 2: 38727 (32.84%)
 3: 7768 (9.88%)
 4: 1153 (1.96%)
 5: 143 (0.30%)
 6: 14 (0.04%)
 7: 1 (0.00%)
```

In contrast, this `Hash` function

```
function Hash(Key : ASB.Bounded_String) return Ada.Containers.Hash_Type is
  S : String := ASB.To_String(Key);
  H : Ada.Containers.Hash_Type := 0;
begin
  for C of S loop
     H := H * 3 + Character'Pos(C);
  end loop;
  return H;
end;
```

produces a result having unique hashes for fewer than half of the words and twenty collisions each for two different hash values in the worst case:

```
Word count: 235886
Table size: 393241
Load factor: 59.99%
 0: 236804 (0.00%)
 1: 107721 (45.67%)
 2: 32247 (27.34%)
 3: 9763 (12.42%)
 4: 3427 (5.81%)
 5: 1431 (3.03%)
 6: 813 (2.07%)
 7: 441 (1.31%)
 8: 250 (0.85%)
 9: 150 (0.57%)
 10: 88 (0.37%)
 11: 41 (0.19%)
 12: 27 (0.14%)
 13: 14 (0.08%)
 14: 11 (0.07%)
 15: 7 (0.04%)
 16: 2 (0.01%)
 17: 1 (0.01%)
 19: 1 (0.01%)
 20: 2 (0.02%)
```